# How to apply css by parent to child component in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular13

I have an `Angular 13` app & a couple of components structure look as below

1. logo component

   ```
   <svg enable-background="new 0 0 2014 1674.641" version="1.1" 
   viewBox="0 0 2014 1674.641" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   </svg>
   ```
2. header component

   ```
   <div class="appHeader">
      <a href="https://mysite"> 
        <app-logo> </app-logo>
      </a>
   ```

I'm trying to set the width & height of the svg (`logo-component`) from the `header-component`

header.component.css

```
  .appHeader svg 
   {
    width: 20rem;
    height: 3.5rem;
   }
```

However, this way CSS intended for svg logo is not reflected. How can I apply CSS to such child component from its parent component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since component style are encapsulated by default. you should use [::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) to disable view-encapsulation for that rule

```
::ng-deep .appHeader svg {
    width: 20rem;
    height: 3.5rem;
 }
```

Comment: ng-deep deprecated

Comment: @Murugan The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

Comment: As of angular 17 using ::ng-deep should be fine I guess

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: @Murugan https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep:~:text=The%20shadow%2Dpiercing%20descendant%20combinator%20is%20deprecated%20and